# Change read status in MYSQL based on the click status in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-2

I've created an inbox which would fetch the messages from mysqldb.

I need to differentiate between read and unread e-mails, which I'm trying to achieve through inline-styling in the row.
I'm trying to do that as soon as a user clicks on the e-mail and opens it, change the status in mysqldb for readstatus flag = "YES", which is "NO" by default.

Howver, it works only for the first row.

### View

```
    <form action="<?php echo BASEURL; ?>home/movetotrash" method="POST" id="emailform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center id="msg"></center>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="10" border="1" class="mailbox">


        <tr class="headrow">
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Date</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
            $id="";
            $read = 0;
            $unread = 0;8*****-
            foreach($row as $alldata)
            {
                $id = $alldata->ID;
                if($alldata->READSTATUS=="YES"){
                $read++;
                echo "<tr id='".$alldata->ID."' bgcolor='lightgray'>";
                }else{
                    $unread++;
                    echo "<tr id='".$alldata->ID."' bgcolor='white'>";
                }
                    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' id='select' value=".$id." onclick='enablebtn()'></td>";
                    echo "<td class='mailcell' name='name[]' id='nameclick'>".$alldata->NAME."</td>";
                    echo "<td class='mailcell' name='sender[]' id='nameclick'>".$alldata->SENDER."</td>";
                    echo "<td class='mailcell' name='subject[]' id='nameclick'>".$alldata->SUBJECT."</td>";
                    echo "<td class='mailcell' name='date[]' id='nameclick'>".$alldata->DATE."</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>

<button type="submit" class="btn-primary" name='movetotrash' id="movetotrash" disabled">Delete</button>
</form>
```

### Controller

```
public function showemail()
{
    $data['row'] = $this->user_model->inboxdb();
    $data['sentemail'] = $this->user_model->sentemaildb();
    $data['draftemail'] = $this->user_model->draftemaildb();
    $data['trashemail'] = $this->user_model->trashemaildb();
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
    $data['emaildata'] = $this->user_model->showemaildb();
    $id = $data['emaildata']->ID;
    $this->user_model->changereadstatus($id);
    $this->load->view("showemail", $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

### Model

```
public function changereadstatus($id)
    {
        $sql="update email set READSTATUS='YES' where ID='$id'";
        $res = $this->db->query($sql);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. Id's _must_ be unique per element (you can not reuse id's, like you've done)

Comment: I either don`t get the question or the code is fussy.. The code given is not related to a single action, rather, it shows the list view as well as the detail view of opening a mail.